# key error problem ,when enter "aa" in lendfuction (in book name)

Tags: python, python-3.x

it is showing an error when i enter "aa"(without quotes in lend_book function in book name ).

```
class library:
    
    def __init__(self,list,library_name):
        self.listofbook = list
        self.library_name = library_name
        self.lendbook = {}
        self.Ldict = {}
    def display_book(self):
        for book in self.listofbook:
            if book not in self.Ldict:
                print(book)
    
    def lend_book(self):
        name_book1 = input('Enter the book you lend\n>')
        name_ur1 = input('Enter your name\n>')
        bdict = {name_book1:name_ur1}
        if name_book1 in self.listofbook:
            self.Ldict.update(bdict)
            self.listofbook.remove(name_book1)
            print("book has been issue to you")
        else:
            print(f"{name_book1} was not available\n{self.Ldict[name_book1]} currently owns the book")
        
    def donate_book(self):
        print("Enter the name or list of book that you wants to donate\n>")
        donate_book = input()     
        self.listofbook.extend(donate_book)
    def return_book(self):
        name_book2 = input('Enter the book you want to return\n>')
        name_ur2 = input('Enter your name\n>')
        bdict2 = {name_book2:name_ur2}
        del self.Ldict[name_book2]
        self.listofbook.extend(name_book2)

    def addBook(self):
        book = input()
        self.listofbook.append(book)
        print("Book has been added to the book list")
    
    def printLend(self):
            if self.Ldict=={}:
                print("No book is lended")
            else:
                print('those who lend books')
                for key in self.Ldict:
                    print(f'Book {key} and Name {self.Ldict[key]}')
        
    def Option(self,a):
        if a==1:
            return self.display_book()
        elif a==2:
            return self.lend_book()
        elif a==3:
            return self.donate_book()
        elif a==4:
            return self.return_book()
        elif a==5:
            return self.printLend()
        elif a==6:
            return self.addBook()
        else:
            print("Enter a vaild option")
if __name__=='__main__':
    sumit = library(["jungalbook","thatbook","a","b","c","d"],"sumit_library")
    while True:
        print(f"Welcome to the {sumit.library_name}")
        print("Enter options to continue")
        print("1-display book")
        print("2-lend book")
        print("3-donate book")
        print("4-return book")
        print("5-details for books were lended")
        print("6-Add book")
        
        op = int(input())
        sumit.Option(op)
        print("Press 'q' to quit and 'c' to continue")
        user_choice2 = ''
        while(user_choice2!="c" and user_choice2!="q"):
            user_choice2 = input()
            if user_choice2 == "q":
                exit()

            elif user_choice2 == "c":
                continue
```

please help

Comment: try to make your code [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), currently most of the code is irrelevant to the problem and does not show the problem with "aa"

Comment: It would appear that `"aa"` is not a book that is listed in `Ldict`. To fix this, you can check `if name_book1 not in self.Ldict: ...` before continuing.